# Best open source license for those wanting attribution?

Tags: open-source, licensing

I've <del>got</del> had concerns of many licenses I've seen having nothing preventing other developers from taking code and claiming it as theirs. A few I've looked at included MIT and CPAL licenses. What licenses could offer some peace of mind in that regard?

Comment: The GPL has attribution clauses, like almost all Free/Open Source licenses.  Did you just miss them when reading it?

Comment: check out http://choosealicense.com/licenses/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about the [Apache 2.0 license](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html):

> You must retain, in the Source form of
>   any Derivative Works that You
>   distribute, all copyright, patent,
>   trademark, and attribution notices
>   from the Source form of the Work,
>   excluding those notices that do not
>   pertain to any part of the Derivative
>   Works; and

But I think you are worrying too much. Most users of FOSS code will happily retain attributions, license or no, and do you really have the financial resources to pursue those few who don't?

Comment: "excluding those notices that do not pertain to any part of the Derivative Works"?

Comment: if I remove your code, I can remove your attribution.

Comment: Sure, why not? Suppose your contribution was a checksum function and I replace it with one that calcs a different checksum type. I could then remove all your code & attributions.

Answer (score 19):

I recommend all software be licensed under the [Poetic License](http://genaud.net/2005/10/poetic-license/):

> (c) <year> <name>
> This work ‘as-is’ we provide.
> No warranty express or implied.
> We’ve done our best,
> to debug and test.
> Liability for damages denied.
>
> Permission is granted hereby,
> to copy, share, and modify.
> Use as is fit,
> free or for profit.
> These rights, on this notice, rely.

It is essentially the MIT license as a limerick. However, I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want. As a joke answer, I community wiki-ed it so people wouldn't think I was rep-whoring.

But I, personally, will be using the Poetic license on as much software as I can justify to myself.

Comment: As much as I love the idea, I'd hate to have to test this one in court.

Comment: True, but it's supposedly more or less identical to the MIT license.

Comment: Actually the disclaimer part needs to be in uppercase: "Capitalization of these particular provisions is a US legal mandate for consumer protection."

Answer (score 6):

The [BSD license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses) has an attribution clause in it:

> Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.

I like the BSD license because it's short, straight forward, and easy to comprehend.

I would compare it with the [Apache 2.0 License](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html) that Neil [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713045/best-open-source-license-for-those-wanting-attribution/713076#713076) and see which one better meets your needs.